# javascript jquery not repeating on similar divs clock not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this html and i need to add as many div class=row with a clock in it.  however something is breaking the code and the clock runs fine on the first div class=row but will break on all subsequent divs so the clocks on 2nd, 3rd, etc are not working.  something is wrong with my javascript... thanks

`

```
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <h4>End Date:&nbsp;</h4>
                        <h5 class="time">04-30-20 15:00:00</h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <div class="clock">
                            <div>
                                <span class="day"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Days</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="hour"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Hours</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="minute"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Minutes</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="second"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Seconds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="closed"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

```
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <h4>End Date:&nbsp;</h4>
                        <h5 class="time">04-30-20 15:00:00</h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <div class="clock">
                            <div>
                                <span class="day"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Days</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="hour"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Hours</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="minute"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Minutes</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="second"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Seconds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="closed"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

```
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <h4>End Date:&nbsp;</h4>
                        <h5 class="time">04-30-20 15:00:00</h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="for-sale-heading">
                        <div class="clock">
                            <div>
                                <span class="day"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Days</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="hour"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Hours</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="minute"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Minutes</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="second"></span>
                                <div class="local-date">Seconds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="closed"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div> 
    </div> 
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var deadline = new Date("apr 30, 2020 15:00:00").getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var t = deadline - now;
            var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementsByClassName("day")[0].innerHTML = days;
            document.getElementsByClassName("hour")[0].innerHTML = hours;
            document.getElementsByClassName("minute")[0].innerHTML = minutes;
            document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].innerHTML = seconds;
            if (t < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementsByClassName("closed")[0].innerHTML = "Auction Closed";
                document.getElementsByClassName("day")[0].innerHTML = '0';
                document.getElementsByClassName("hour")[0].innerHTML = '0';
                document.getElementsByClassName("minute")[0].innerHTML = '0';
                document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].innerHTML = '0';
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pXia.jpg)

[image]

Comment: maybe using id would be better but i can not use repeating id's unless i can find a way to increment id + 1 but that complicates things even more on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("day")[0].innerHTML = days;
 document.getElementsByClassName("hour")[0].innerHTML = hours;
 document.getElementsByClassName("minute")[0].innerHTML = minutes;
 document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].innerHTML = seconds;
```

in the code above notice the [0] behind each element. You are setting the first element in the selected list. In order for this to work as expected you need to put that section in a for loop and actually set all the elements returned by the selectors. The same is true for the check below.

on the second attempt:

```
case "day":
    console.log("day");
    el.innerHTML = days;
    /*or if you want to use jquery */
    $('.day').html(days);
    break;
```

className is an attribute and does not have innerHTML property. 
The next line has an invalid selector when you use jquery you need to specify the type of attribute before the value. Since you are searching for class attribute the correct selector is '.' or '[class="......."]'. If set correctly bot lines will do the same thing however:
 1. the first line will set the element that is passed in the form loop, 
 2. the second will update all elements with the proper selector(making the loop obsolete).

Comment: yes that was dumb of me to overlook that.. but it still doesn't solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

[clock image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi6pP.jpg)

well this still doesnt answer my question.. i need to populate the collection .. i tried something like this but not working either; i want the days minutes, hours, seconds to appear and function in real time

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var deadline = new Date("apr 30, 2020 15:00:00").getTime();

        var x = setInterval(function() {

            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var t = deadline - now;
            var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            var els = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
                console.log(el.className);
                console.log(el.getElementsByClassName);
                switch (el.className) {
                    case "day":
                        console.log("day");
                        el.className.innerHTML = days;
                        $('day').innerHTML = days;
                        break;
                    case "hour":
                        console.log("hour");
                        el.className.innerHTML = hours;
                        $('hours').innerHTML = hours;
                        break;
                    case "minute":
                        console.log("minute");
                        el.className.innerHTML = minutes;
                        $('minute').innerHTML = minutes;
                        break;
                    case "second":
                        console.log("second");
                        el.className.innerHTML = seconds;
                        $('second').innerHTML = seconds;
                        break;
                }



}); }, 1000);});
```

Comment: update your original post. and remove this one. Such posts make the thread difficult to follow, I edite my post above with the answer